# High CPU usage, low memory usage on Mariadb 10.5.8 -- SQL tuner complaining about memory, performance seems fine

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.5

I'm hoping to get some friendly advice how to proceed with optimizing this server.

VM:
8vCPU - 2.6GHz
32GB mem

Disk speed
~3Gbps (380MBps)

Application is Librenms

[my.cnf.d/server.cnf](https://pastebin.com/MV0e9CyW)  -- Built from template somewhere on github

[mysqltuner.pl output](https://pastebin.com/yheXKCcv)

The server currently idles at around 500% cpu with Mariadb being the culprit

[sar -q output](https://pastebin.com/PzUDHdXK)

[free -m output](https://pastebin.com/1t0wwwZZ)

Comment: I've added some information that I find hilarious....  /etc/my.cnf doesn't have any includes for the /etc/my.cnf.d directory, thus none of the changes I've made were ever changed.

I've copied the file /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf to /etc/my.cnf and I'm having a whole new world of problems.  I'm assuming I need to stop the service and clean out innodb. I should have more information available in an hour.  This was brought to my attention when I realized I couldn't change any of the logging variables.

Comment: It varies slightly on RPM distros /etc/my.cnf is read, on Deb based /etc/mysql/my.cnf is read. I'm not sure what you mean by 'clean out innodb', sounds scary. These files are only read on startup.

Comment: Here is the config I'm working with:
https://pastebin.com/eLwGPXmd

Comment: "Clean out innodb" was referring to the comments at the top of my first server.cnf file that said I would need to purge the logs.  That wasn't the issue.  Once I got mysql logging, I had to run through the hoops of deprecated options/variables and file permission errors for socket and pid.  I soaked the new config for about 15 minutes before I abandoned it and went back to stock.  I added a few variables to the config for innodb pool and log buffer and file size as well as max connections.  CPU still high, but more memory is being used.

Comment: Comments are important in the config files; the processing time for them is _insignificant_.

Answer (score 3):

Increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to be about 70% of *available* RAM.

High CPU implies poor indexing and/or poor query formulation.  Let's see some queries and the matching `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

```
 INDEX(`rule_id`,`device_id`,`state`)  -- handles the following:
 INDEX(`rule_id`,`device_id`)   -- DROP
 INDEX(`rule_id`)   -- DROP
```

Add

```
 INDEX(state, time_logged)
```

Shrink `INTs` to some smaller datatype.  Saving space speeds up the query a little.

Invert the query -- Find the 50 rows, *then* do the `JOINs`:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM (
        SELECT id FROM log
            WHERE ...
            ORDER BY  time_logged DESC
            LIMIT  0,50
         )
    JOIN log AS e USING(id)  -- to get other columns from log
    JOIN the other tables for the other columns
    ORDER BY  time_logged DESC  -- repeat if ORDER matters
```

Use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the slowlog; it will be easier to spot the "worst" queries.

Other issues...

- `max_connections = 200000` is ridiculously high, even dangerously high.  That is the number of "connections" to allow at any one time.  RAM is consumed for each connection.  Do `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';` to see that you have not come anywhere near that value.  `100` is a safe starting value until you have a reason to increase it.
- Notice (in slowlog) `Rows_examined: 973090`.  How many rows in each of the tables?  The changes I suggest will probably bring that number down, though probably not down to the optimal of 50 (as in `Rows_sent: 50`).
- An owl can turn its head almost all the way around.  That is how my head feels when I see a `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` in the same statement.  My head would appreciate it if you could turn that `RIGHT JOIN` into a suitable `LEFT JOIN` or, if appropriate, `INNER JOIN`.  In particular, in the queries with `AND  R.severity >= 2`, it really is an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I'm just now getting around to slow queries.  All the slow queries seem to be originating from the web front end, which people are consistently logged into all day long. I think the widgets are performing these queries...  Here are the whoppers:  https://pastebin.com/QgxS836u  I set the slow time to 1.  There are some 10 seconders in there that I'm assuming are causing occasional spike.  Here is the SHOW CREATE TABLE info for this alert_log table:  https://pastebin.com/YHBgEe5w  I also set log_queries_not_using_indexes=1 and the slow log reached 100MB in about 2 mins.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  As far as the queries go, I will probably need to suggest these to the librenms team as this isn't my application.  The max connections after running for less than one hour is 366.  I will lower to 1000 for starters.  I definitely overdid that one...

Comment: @choseph - `log_queries_not_using_indexes=1` leads to a lot of useless noise, especially after the tables have been filling up for some time.  Leave it off.  Come back periodically to run the slowlog (without that setting); that way you will eventually become aware of such a missing index.

Comment: @choseph - Yes, 1000 should be good.  If you do exceed that, check that the clients are disconnecting; check for the web server allowing lots of "children" unnecessarily, etc.

Comment: We performed the inverted query and it runs 2000 times faster, but there is logic to why they're doing it that way.  There's information in the alert rules table that can be ordered by, so the pagination has to exist on the outer layer.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @choseph - Here's a kludge:  Increase the `LIMIT` to `200` in the subquery; then add the desired `LIMIT 50` on the outer query.  If the desired 50 are found in 200, it will work.  Else there will be too few.

Comment: @choseph - (re 2000x) -- The `973090` probably dropped by a lot.  Oh, I guess it would no longer be in the slowlog.  Maybe some other query is now the slowest?

Comment: I've passed the info on to the development team.  We're querying 6200+ devices, which is one of the larger deployments.  I think we're going to have to live with the high CPU utilization until changes can be made in their application.  I appreciate your help!  Definitely helped my understanding of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysqltuner.pl report is from 11 seconds of uptime - this is too short a sample to reach significant conclusions on its output. Repost after 24 hrs of uptime. Include "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS" too.

Disable query cache. It has high contention and slows most queries down

As Rick said, focus on slow queries by looking through the slow query log. [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html)

With log_queries_not_using_indexes=1 you will get significant amount low value log items. Set [min_examined_row_limit=1000](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#min_examined_row_limit) to minimize the noise.

long_query_time might be more appropriate to be 1 (second) or less.

[log-slow-verbosity=query_plan,explain](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/) will include explain info in the slow log. See [MySQL: Building the best INDEX for a given SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for creating the right indexes for a query.

Feel free to ask further questions on tuning queries/indexes with the query, `EXPLAIN {query}` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` output.

Ps: other mysqltuner output - ignore recommendations about mariadb.sys, its a locked account.

Comment: I've updated the SQL tuner output:
https://pastebin.com/CCgGf8zM

Thanks!

Comment: Despite not picking up configuration changes it highlights Query cache to disable, no slow queries (due to above settings not being picked up), and Temp tables on disk being high (better indexing needed - slow query log should show these). 28% writes is something to keep an eye on if any write queries end up in the slow query log (like increasing innodb_log_file_size).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Hx7kzUJf  . I've shored up the query cache warnings.  The output looks healthier now.  I also enabled performance schema and increased my innodb log file size (6G) to 25% of my pool size (24G).  Only general recommendations!  mariadb process is still floating between 240-650%.  I'm assuming that is going to be best troubleshot through slow query identification?

Comment: My current my.cnf file FYI:
https://pastebin.com/5uATfpfM

Comment: Virtually every "production" server should have _both_ `query_cache_type = OFF` and `query_cache_size = 0`.  This will (usually) _improve_ performance.

Comment: @choseph - To get a feel for whether the log_file_size is appropriate, I need to see several metrics.   http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: @choseph Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @choseph Your last posted MySQLTuner report was for 1 minute.  Please produce the report after minimum 24 hours UPTIME.  You still have max_connections at 10000, please reduce to 1000 to be a more reasonable number.  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections'; will reveal how many max concurrent connections have been used since instance start. Welcome to SE.